# Netflix Numbering in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to make this UI, but it seems really hard. The card Images with numbers and shadow on them.

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code solution with comments, uploaded to GitHub:

[GitHub Repository] https://github.com/Itay-Lavi/flutter-netflix-numbering-ui

[Website Demo] https://movies-nunbering-ui.netlify.app/#/

Image:
[image]

Main Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './cards.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      title: 'Netflix Stacked Listview Demo',
      home: const Cards(),
    );
  }
}

//Make Drag available in horizontal in web
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

Cards Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './item_card.dart';

class Cards extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cards({super.key});

  @override
  State<Cards> createState() => _CardsState();
}

class _CardsState extends State<Cards> {
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Runs only after all widgets builded
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToEnd(context));
  }

//Scroll to the start, because list is reversed
  void _scrollToEnd(BuildContext context) {
    controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ItemCard> cards = [];

    stackedList() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cards.add(ItemCard(index: i));
      }
      //Reversed to make up on the reverse boolean in listview
      cards = cards.reversed.toList();
    }

//generate array, should get array from state management / API
    stackedList();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 8, 8, 8),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        //Reverse is set to make left card stacked over the right card
        reverse: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            widthFactor: 0.94, //Cuts the card (Cutting the number)
            child: cards[index],
          );
        },
        itemCount: cards.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Card Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  const ItemCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String cardNumStr = (index + 1).toString();
    const double fontSize = 280;
    const double fontHeight =
        1.66; //RichText vertical padding, need to be calibrated every change in font or height size
    const Color borderColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 191, 191, 191);

    return SizedBox(
      width: 325,
      height: 380,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              //Card Shadow
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 8, 8, 8),
                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                    offset: Offset(30, 0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              width: 250,
              height: 380,
              //Image Card
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://picsum.photos/id/$index/250/400',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Number Text
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                //Grey Border With Shadow
                Text(
                  cardNumStr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      shadows: const [
                        Shadow(blurRadius: 12, color: borderColor),
                      ],
                      height: fontHeight,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: fontSize,
                      //www.kindacode.com/snippet/adding-a-border-to-text-in-flutter/
                      foreground: Paint()
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                        ..strokeWidth = 6.5
                        ..color = borderColor),
                ),
                //Black Text Over White Text
                Text(
                  cardNumStr,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    height: fontHeight,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: fontSize,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 18, 18),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for you, you can do some more configurations if you want to

```
ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Image.network(
                              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=$index',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  // Stroked text as border.
                                  Text(
                                    "${index + 1}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 100,
                                      shadows: [
                                        Shadow(
                                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                          offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                                        ),
                                        // font size and color of the text
                                      ],
                                      foreground: Paint()
                                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                                        ..strokeWidth = 6
                                        ..color = Colors.grey.shade500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Solid text as fill.
                                  Text(
                                    "${index + 1}",
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 100,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

Output will look like this

[image]